# C++ Searching an array for a number but does not trigger else statement if it is not found

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

```
int gas;
// Input Code   
int user_code;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Please enter the Code: ";
std::cin >> user_code;
std::cout << "The value you entered is " << user_code;
std::cout << std::endl;

int array1[16] = { 42011, 42017, 42029, 42045, 
                   42091, 42101, 34001, 34005,    
                   34007, 34009, 34011, 34015, 
                   34033, 10001, 10003, 24015 }; // 0.2387    (23.87%)

int array2[45] = { 11001, 24003, 24510, 24005, 24009,
                   24013, 24017, 24019, 24021, 24025, 
                   24027, 24029, 24031, 24033, 24035, 
                   24037, 24041, 24043, 51510, 51013, 
                   51043, 51047, 51600, 51059, 51610, 
                   51061, 51069, 51630, 51099, 51107, 
                   51683, 51685, 51153, 51157, 51177, 
                   51179, 51187, 51840, 54003, 54027, 
                   54037, 54065, 42001, 42055, 42133 }; //0.2710 (27.10%)

int * array1_search;
array1_search = std::find(array1, array1+ 16, user_code);

int * array2_search;
array2_search = std::find(array2, array2 + 45, user_code);


if (array1_search != array1+ 16) {
    std::cout << "Codefound in Array1: " << *array1_search << '\n';
    gas= 0.2387;

}

else if (array2_search != array2_search + 45) {
    std::cout << "Code found in Array2: " << *array2_search << '\n';
    gas= 0.2710;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Not found \n";
    gas= 0.1506;
}
```

Above is my current code.  I am trying to have the user input a variable user_code value and then iterate over the two arrays array1[16] and array2[45].  If the user input value is on the first array1 I want to assign gas 0.2387 and if the input value is on the other array2 I want to assign gas 0.2710, and if it is not within any array gas should be 0.1506.

So basically I want to assign a value depending on which array the user's input is contained in.  I am very new to c++, what is the best way to go about this?

It seems to work fine if I enter a number that is within array1 or array2 and it correctly identifies that is found in array1 or array2.  The problem is when I enter a number I know is not within either array to trigger the else statement it identifies it as being in array2.  For example, when I enter 12345 as a user_code it says "Code found in Array2: 0".  I know 12345 is not contained in array2 and I do not understand why *array2_search is assigned 0.  What can I do to fix this so if a user_code is entered that is not contained within array1 or array2 it goes to the else statement?

Comment: `int` variables don't have fractions. You're assigning `0` to `gas` every time.

Comment: Don't hard-code numbers like `16` and `45` all over the place. Declare a named constant.

Comment: `if (array1_search != array1+ 16) {` -- Please use `if (array1_search != std::end(array1))`.  Also, it is very easy to make a mistake with numbers such as `45` being used as the value.  What if you had `44` entries, and you miscounted and thought there were 45 entries?  Your code would still compile, but will end up with the wrong results.  Instead let the compiler do the counting. i.e. `int array2[] = { whatever };`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, gas is a double in the original

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (array2_search != array2_search + 45) {
```

Should be

```
else if (array2_search != array2 + 45) {
```

or better using [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) of C++11:

```
if (array1_search != std::end(array1)) {
```

```
else if (array2_search != std::end(array2)) {
```

And `int gas;` => `double gas;` if you want to be able to store floating point values, not just integers (0.2387 and 0.2710 would give integer 0).

Answer (score 0):

Using standard containers and newer c++ features if you have C++11 minimum you can then do something like this:

```
int main() {
    // Use Constants Instead of "Hard Coded Values" 
    // If you noticed these are not even needed.
    // const unsigned code1 = 16;
    // const unsigned code2 = 45;

    // Made gas a float instead of an int due to the decimal values
    // I also initialized it with the default value if the code is 
    // not found in either container.
    float gas = 0.1506f; // Default Price If Not Found

    // created your first array as a const std::vector<int> and
    // used its initializer list to populate its contents: this vector
    // can not be modified: remove the const if this container
    // will need to have entries added in the future.
    const std::vector<int> arr1 { 42011, 42017, 42029, 42045,
                                  42091, 42101, 34001, 34005,
                                  34007, 34009, 34011, 34015,
                                  34033, 10001, 10003, 24015 }; // 0.2387 (23.87%)

    // did the same for the second array
    const std::vector<int> arr2 { 11001, 24003, 24510, 24005, 24009,
                                  24013, 24017, 24019, 24021, 24025,
                                  24027, 24029, 24031, 24033, 24035,
                                  24037, 24041, 24043, 51510, 51013,
                                  51043, 51047, 51600, 51059, 51610,
                                  51061, 51069, 51630, 51099, 51107,
                                  51683, 51685, 51153, 51157, 51177,
                                  51179, 51187, 51840, 54003, 54027,
                                  54037, 54065, 42001, 42055, 42133 }; //0.2710 (27.10%)

    // No changes made here same basic user I/O.
    int user_code = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter the Code: ";
    std::cin >> user_code;
    std::cout << "The value you entered is " << user_code;
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Created 2 flags for later.
    bool b1found = false;
    bool b2found = false;

    // auto for loop ranged based.
    for ( auto code : arr1 ) {
        if ( code == user_code ) {
            b1found = true; // Set flag
            gas = 0.2387f;  // Set new gas
            // Output code & gas
            std::cout << "Code found in Arr1: " << code << '\n';
            std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
        }
    }

    for ( auto code : arr2 ) {
        if ( code == user_code ) {
            b2found = true; // set flag
            gas = 0.2710f;  // set gas
            // output code & gas
            std::cout << "Code found in Arr2: " << code << '\n';
            std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
        }
    }

    // If code not found in either output "not found" and display default gas
    if ( !b1found && !b2found ) {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
        std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
    }   

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

You can even simplify this a little more by removing the two bool flags. We know that if a value is found in `arr1` or `arr2` that the `gas` value will be changed, So all we really have to do is check to see if it has been changed.

```
// auto for loop ranged based.
for ( auto code : arr1 ) {
    if ( code == user_code ) {
        gas = 0.2387f;  // Set new gas
        // Output code & gas
        std::cout << "Code found in Arr1: " << code << '\n';
        std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
    }
}

for ( auto code : arr2 ) {
    if ( code == user_code ) {
        gas = 0.2710f;  // set gas
        // output code & gas
        std::cout << "Code found in Arr2: " << code << '\n';
        std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
    }
}

const float defaultGas = 0.1506;
// If code not found in either output "not found" and display default gas
if ( gas == defaultGas ) {
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
    std::cout << "gas = " << gas << '\n';
}
```